# Grails controller names and URL mappings

Tags: rest, grails

I am using grails 3 and I would like to know how the controller names are resolved. Apparently, if the `UrlMappings.groovy` contains

```
static mappings = {
    "/test"(controller: 'test', action: 'index')
}
```

Then a class `TestController` is needed. However, if I have a controller named `TestValueController`, then the mapping

```
static mappings = {
    "/test"(controller: 'testvalue', action: 'index')
}
```

does not work. How can I use a controller with a camel case name? More generally, for a controller named XController, which string should be used in the `mappings` section?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That works fine, except that it's case-sensitive - `testvalue` should be `testValue`.

Comment: Well, but what is the connection between the controller name and the required string? How does the lookup work?

Comment: It's the 'artifact name' - remove the artifact suffix (in this case 'Controller') and lowercase the first letter. But if the class name starts with multiple uppercase letters don't lowercase, e.g. the name for 'XMLController' would be 'XML', not 'xML', to be consistent with JavaBean naming rules. To avoid dealing with that I usually avoid multiple uppercase and call the controller 'XmlController'